# what is "engineName" property in TI gstreamer plugin TIVidenc1

Tags: gstreamer, texas-instruments

What is "**engineName**" property in TI Gstreamer plugin **TIVidenc1**?
And what values it can be?
(I know only codecServer... what else it can be?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [documentation](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GstTIPlugin_Elements#TIVidenc1) of TI(not too much explanation):

> Engine name used by codec combo.

[Here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Example_GStreamer_Pipelines) are some good examples of usage.

I have seen also this value

- encode (used in network streaming but also H264 encoding to file)

With element TIVidenc I seen also:
- hmjcp (used with H264 encoding)

You can use `gst-inspect TIVidenc1` to check the values (hope they are listed there) if you have installed this plugin/expansion or whatever it is..

also if you are keen you can check the [sources](https://gstreamer.ti.com/gf/project/gstreamer_ti/scmsvn/)